# Redirect back to same application as if typing the URL in address bar? (Not a Postback)

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Silly question,

Is there a way to redirect an application back to it's self from a button or a hyperlink (without a simple postback), as if you were typing the application's url in the address bar for the first time?

The reason I ask is because I have an application with a parent web form and then Telerik RadMultiPage that renders each page (or web user control) one at a time. I do not have the option to use the "RenderSelectedPageOnly" property in this case because I want the user to be able to navigate between pages with the TabStrip.

On the very last page, I want the user to be able to start the application all over, as if visiting the URL for the first time. The application is session based and when landing on the last page, I clear all session variables (Personal Information). On the last child page, I have put a button with `Response.Redirect("default.aspx", true);` event. The problem is that previous pages contain `if` statements that basically listen for certain session variables and act accordingly.

When I run the `Response.Redirect("default.aspx", true);` on the last PageView, I get "object reference not set to an instance of an object". I know it's because of Session variables that no longer  exists but this happens because all MultiPage views are still loaded on a postback.

Any way to just simulate typing a url in the address bar and hitting submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this very easily with javascript.

**Javascript**

```
function ReloadMe() { window.location = window.location.href; }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Reload Me" onclick="ReloadMe()" />
```

Comment: I like we're it's going but its still just running a regular post-back. Maybe it's by button. I'll try a hyperlink.

Comment: Check my updated answer. That code would emulate the exact same thing as if a user typed the url into their browser. You did use a straight HTML button, and not an ASP button right?

Comment: You can add `return false;` to the end of the `OnClientClick` method if you are using ASP.NET buttons :)

Comment: Hmm, well I did try both the asp.net button and a regular HTML button but both ask to resend data and essentially perform a post-back. I don't know if it's technically still a post-back for sure but I'm still getting the "object reference" error from another PageView. I've tried simply placing a hyperlink on the page that links back to the URL but same thing. It's different when I manually type and submit the URL in the address bar though.

Comment: That's odd, and seems like there is something wrong elsewhere, but try this instead of the location.reload.   `window.location = window.location.href`

Comment: That did exactly what I wanted...`window.location = window.location.href`. I appreciate it.